# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status') using slash commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using discord.js v13 and I receive the following error when trying to use the member presence to check their status:

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'status')
    at /home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/slashcmds/utilidad/serverinfo.js:59:76
    at Map.filter (/home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/collection/dist/index.js:1:2066)
    at Object.run (/home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/slashcmds/utilidad/serverinfo.js:59:43)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/index.js:43:18)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:70:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:350:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/DinBot-Slash-CMDS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:300:10)*
```

Code:

```
const members = interaction.guild.members.cache;
  .addField('Presencia', 
      `**Conectado:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online').size}\n` + 
      `**Ausentes:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'idle').size}\n` + 
      `**No Molestar:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'dnd').size}\n` + 
      `**Desconectado:** ${members.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'offline').size}\n` + '\u200b'
   )
```

Comment: I Have Defined Members With :
```const members = interaction.guild.members.cache;```

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent is enabled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68528046/6126373

In v13, the `presence` property [can now be `null`](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildmember-presence), so make sure you also check that by using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or by checking if `member.presence` is truthy:

```js
members.filter((member) => member.presence?.status === 'online').size;

// OR

members.filter((member) => member.presence && member.presence.status === 'online').size;
```

Comment: it shows 0 everytime

Comment: Have you enabled the `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent?